# How to get current directory in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Assuming that my JS file is in /libs/qrcode/qrcode.js and i have another file qrcode.html at /libs/qrcode/, is it possible to get current directory/path (i.e. /libs/qrcode/) inside the qrcode.js?

what i'm trying to do is to load qrcode.html in the webview inside qrcode.js without worrying where is the qrcode folder reside in the Resource directory.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Try `Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory` or `Ti.includeAbsolute`

This should give you the path from your `Resources` folder or take a look at the [Titanium.Filesystem.File](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.Filesystem.File.parent-method.html)